# using sub query and join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

query to display the book code, publication, price and supplier name of the book which is taken frequently.

The above question I used this query but it return error.

```
select b1.book_code,b2.publication,b2.price,b3.supplier_name 
from BOOK_ISSUE b1 
join BOOK_DETAILS b2 on b1.BOOK_CODE=b2.BOOK_CODE 
join SUPPLIERS_DETAILS b3 on b2.SUPPLIER_ID=b3.SUPPLIER_ID 
group by b1.BOOK_CODE 
having COUNT(b1.book_code)>1
```

the query explanation is:
table1: book_issue
table2: book_details
table3: supplieer_details

the above query purpose is want to display frequently taken book. I tried but having some.

How to correct the sql statement?

Comment: Post sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use columns in `SELECT` clause that is not part of `GROUP BY` without aggregate function, because there is no way for RDMBS to tell which row out of the group you meant to select.

There are several ways to deal with it depending on your desired outcome:

1. Include columns in `GROUP BY` clause
2. Use an aggregate function `MIN()`, `MAX()` ...
3. Use a subquery to return a grouped resultset and then `JOIN` it with other tables

It's hard to tell without seeing table structures, sample data and desired output but you can try

```sql
SELECT b1.book_code,
       b2.publication,
       b2.price,
       b3.supplier_name 
  FROM
(
  SELECT book_code
    FROM book_issue
   GROUP BY book_code
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b1 JOIN book_details b2 
     ON b1.book_code = b2.book_code JOIN suppliers_details b3 
     ON b2.supplier_id = b3.supplier_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly based on the question, but it could be as simple as:

```
select b1.book_code,b2.publication,b2.price,b3.supplier_name 
from BOOK_ISSUE b1 
join BOOK_DETAILS b2 on b1.BOOK_CODE=b2.BOOK_CODE 
join SUPPLIERS_DETAILS b3 on b2.SUPPLIER_ID=b3.SUPPLIER_ID 
group by b1.book_code,b2.publication,b2.price,b3.supplier_name
having COUNT(*)>1
```